# Calculate average error via aggregation pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to find the average error for predictions made n-1, n-2, ... n-5 hours before an event happens. One "row" of my data looks like this:
note: _id is the time_collected.

```
{'_id': 5pm,
 'value_at_time_collected': 72,
 'predictions': [
    {'prediction': 77, 'time': 6pm},
    ... 
    {'prediction': 79, 'time': 10pm},
 ]
}
```

With one aggregate I can come up with a time difference and isolate the predictions:

```
pipeline1 = [
    { "$unwind" : "$predictions" },
    { "$project" : 
     {
       "timeDiff" : { "$subtract": ["$predictions.time", "$t_id"]},
       "madeFor" : "$predictions.time",
       "_id":0,
       "estimate": "$predictions.prediction"     
     }}]
list(col.aggregate(pipeline3))
```

Resulting in a dataset like:

```
[{u'estimate': 77.60785714285714,
  u'madeFor': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 28, 0, 0),
  u'timeDiff': 3600000L}, ... ]
```

But I still need to match these with the corresponding **"time_collected"** to calculate the errors, i.e.

```
`$subtract[prediction,value_at_time_collected]`
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Documents not valid and unclear what you are asking

Comment: @user3100115 So I removed the _id field to make it more clear what the fields are, perhaps that's what you meant by not valid. I'm trying to calculate average errors.

Comment: `time: 6pm` is not valid

Comment: @user3100115 pretend it's a datetime.datetime()